# Android - How to access an element data of a list that's inside another list?

Tags: android, json, list

Hy guys, I have encountered an issue with the lists.

What I want to do is to have a list of BasicNameValuePair elements, with this parameters:

- previewUrl
- artistName
- trackName
- artistViewUrl
- artworkUrl100

I retrieve these informations from a JSON file.

I have to store this list INSIDE another list, which stores 10 elements of this kind.

I declared this two lists:

1. `public static List<NameValuePair> songsInfo = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);`
2. `static List dieciCanzoni = new ArrayList(10);`

So the #2 must contain 10 elements of the #1.

How can I access data contained in the list inside the other list?

Please give me some advices, thank you all!

**EDIT:
Maybe I've found the solution!**

Like suggested above, I've created generic String Lists and the code to control the data inside is this:

dieciCanzoni.get(i).get(5).compareTo("previewUrl")==0

I can use get(5) because I know that it will be the last value in the list, right?

Comment: instead of get(5); to get last value, use list.get(list.size()); list.size returns the lenght of it which is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List.get(ELEMENT_AT);
```

This retrives a list(in this case) of what ever kind of element of this list. Once you get a list, retrive what its in the list by doing it again.

```
List.get(ELEMENT_AT).get(ELEMENT_AT);
```

This will retrive an element(LIst) of the first list, and get an element in side.

But to make a List within a List, you need to do this:

```
List<CLASS> listParent=new ArrayList<CLASS>();
List<CLASS_IN> listChild=new ArrayList<CLASS_IN>();
addStuff();
for(...){
listParent.add(listChild);
}
```

Comment: Ok but I must associate a tag with the specified value, otherwise how can I tell the previewUrl or the artistUrl? I was using the NameValuePair list to assign the tag for each attribute, so I could do something like list.get(location).getName()=="previewUrl". Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I've found the solution!

Comment: To my knowledge(without googleing) NameValuePair is a class, you can set that as your CLASS_IN, so list.get(INT).get(INT).getName()==SO.com.